# Why UITabBar works weirdly in iOS 13?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbar

I have code to handle UITabBarItem using swift 4.2.
It can be opened only if that page is already bought.
This is my code

```
func setupTabBar(){
    tabBarItems = tabBar.items
    if(typePage == "ばんそう"){
        self.selectedIndex = 0
        if(pageInfo?.pdfFiles == ""){
            tabBarItems![1].image = UIImage(named: "ic_cross_gray")
            tabBarItems![1].title = "ドリル"
        } else {
            if !IAPHandler.instance.lockHandler(isDrill: true, bookType: IAPHandler.instance.typeFilter(type: titleNav)!) {
                tabBarItems![1].image = UIImage(named: "ic_lock")
                tabBarItems![1].title = "ドリル"
            }
        }
    } else if(typePage == "ドリル") {
        self.selectedIndex = 1
        if(pageInfo?.song.count == 0){
            tabBarItems![0].image = UIImage(named: "ic_cross_gray")
            tabBarItems![0].title = "ばんそう"
        } else {
            if !IAPHandler.instance.lockHandler(isDrill: false, bookType: IAPHandler.instance.typeFilter(type: titleNav)!) {
                tabBarItems![0].image = UIImage(named: "ic_lock")
                tabBarItems![0].title = "ばんそう"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The functionality is working perfectly. But there is a bug on UI iOS 13.
this is the screenshot in iPhone 6 with iOS 12.

[image]

But it's weird when I run on iPhone X with iOS 13.
Same code, same everything, just run on the different devices.

[image]